# React - User Authentication

Tags: reactjs, react-router, authorization, react-router-dom

I have created a simple page that follows the following logic:

When a user opens the page, a request is sent to the back-end (ComponentDidMount) to check the user is valid, if valid, a response is passed to the client to approve access. Now that I have a valid user in state, I want to be able to direct approved users to content & forbidden users towards a forbidden component.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export default class SiteAdmin extends Component {

constructor(props){
    super(props);
      this.state ={
        validUser: false
    }
  }

componentDidMount () {
    if(localStorage.jwtToken){
        this.checkUserIsValid();
      } 
    }

   async checkUserIsValid (){
        //Validate User against backend
        await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/portal/site-admin/validate-user')
        .then(res => {
            if (res.status === 200) {
                this.setState({validUser : true});
            }
        }).catch(err => {
        })
    }

render() {
    return (
        <div className="contentBody">
            {console.log(this.state.validUser)}
        </div>
    )
}
}
```

I have tried a few different approaches to validate this user to this page & I am now confusing getting myself tied in knots and I am looking for some advice on how I should direct validated users towards the correct containers.

In the code sample above, the console reads (false, false, true), I tested the render timings and you get a quick snippet of the 'restricted' component before it renders correctly.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Even though your example code doesn't use react router, I see you've added the tag for react router and my guess is that you're using it. I would take a look at [this guide](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/auth-workflow) which does what  I think you want.  It does not rely on `componentDidMount` but rather the concept of protected routes.

Comment: Thanks Henrik. Yes, I am using React Router. I am using Private Routes in App.js and can get it to work based on role whilst routing. I was getting myself tied in knots trying to check if the user is legitimate on each component with a call to the server. Using react router in this way only on the client, is there a risk that it can be manipulated in the client to obtain access to 'private' routes without a call to the server to validate?

Comment: Every request to react (inside a react router switch) is handled by react router first regardless of whether or not the user navigated there or came via direct URL. This negates the need to check in each and every component. I hope that answers your question.

Comment: Thanks Henrik. This helps!